# Show that if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are elements of a group then $(a_1\cdots a_n)^{-1} =a_n^{-1} \cdots a_1^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, inverse

> Show that if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are elements of a group then $(a_1\cdots a_n)^{-1} =a_n^{-1} \cdots a_1^{-1}$

I understand how to show it for just two elements $a$ and $b$, but how do I show it for $n$ elements? Is it basically the same proof?

Comment: Fix the title! The title and the question are not the same.

Comment: In the title you have $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ where you need $(a_1 \cdots a_n). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy did you notice the powers? $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)^{-2}=a_n^2,\ldots,a_1^2 \not= (a_1\cdots a_n)^{-1} =a_n^{-1} \cdots a_1^{-1}$

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan : That's exactly what I said.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you were mainly concerned with the ',,'. I was talking about the power: $2$ in the title, $-1$ in the body

Answer (score 4):

Use induction on $n$. The base case is $n=2$, and assuming the statement is true for the product of $n-1$ elements, it is true for $n$ elements since $$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)^{-1}=(a_1(a_2\cdots a_n))^{-1}=(a_2\cdots a_n)^{-1}a_1^{-1}$$